# Testing if the Editfield is editable using LeanFt

Tags: assert, uft

We have an editfield that is detected as a Winforms editfield in the object identification center of LeanFt when it is spied upon.
Whether it is editable or not depends on some pre-conditions. Depending on the pre-conditions we recreate, i would like to test if the editfield is editable or not. 
I would like to do something like

```
Assert.assertEquals(false, txtEditfield.isEditable());
```

However I could not find a isEditable method in the [SDK](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/JavaSDKReference/com/hp/lft/sdk/winforms/EditField.html).
Please advise how this can be done.